# Distributing shared data among C++ objects

Tags: c++, constructor, shared-ptr

I am attempting to construct a bunch of objects that can share data, but aren't coupled to each other.  What I want is for the fields of each object to be a `shared_ptr` to whatever data they need.  Once all the objects are created, this will fulfill all my needs, but my issue is how to distribute the information needed to create the `shared_ptr`'s, since the types can be anything.

I will be creating all objects that share a set of data at once inside a factory object.  Also, each shared field will have an enum entry to signify the attribute type (not data type).  For instance the enum will have an entry that is `Position`, and every object that needs position information will use enum to key into a map to find the information it needs to create the `shared_ptr`.

What I want from my system is this:

1. Pass an `SetEnum` to the factory, which defines which "set" of objects to create, along with an optional `map<AttributeEnum, ??>` that defines the initial data of set of objects
2. Create the necessary objects, using a `map<AttributeEnum, ??>` to create `shared_ptr`'s as fields in each of the objects.  If the object needs a field corresponding to a specific value of `AttributeEnum`, it will pull its value from the map.  If that value is not a key in the map, it will create it with a default value, and add it to the map for future objects to use.  This step can be done during or after construction if a method with a template type would be helpful to solve the issue.

The issue is that I want errors at compile time, not run time.  How can I map `AttributeEnum` to a type?  For example, every field corresponding to an `AttributeEnum` value of `Position` will have type `shared_ptr<double>`, but I want a compile error if I attempt to associate `Position` with, for instance, `shared_ptr<int>`.  My question is how to go about this?

A couple different systems I have thought of (albeit none of them ensure the errors at compile time):

1. Pass around a `std::map<Enum, shared_ptr<void> >` and static cast the `shared_ptr`'s to the appropriate types.
2. Construct the objects, then iterate through the Enum, checking each object for which attributes it needs, then passing the proper pointers to it.
3. Having one object "own" each attribute, and force the other to get the information via a message-passing system.

I am considering storing two parallel sets of data, the `AttributeEnum` having entry `Position`, and compiler constants that would define the types such as `#define POSITION double`, then I would simply use `POSITION` for the type where ever I must, but this would make the code much harder to read.

Comment: You want objects whose fields are defined at run time? Are you sure that's the best design for the problem you're trying to solve? How will you use them?

Comment: Sounds like pointer swizzling.

Comment: read docs about [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/any.html) and/or [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant.html) before starting to invent your own solution

Comment: @Beta Not quite (I don't think).  I will have many unrelated objects with a field `Position` which will be `shared_ptr<type>`, all defined independently.  What I want is a way to ensure that the `type` is the same in every class at compile time, for every field described as `Position`.

Comment: @zaufi I ran into boost::any before, but wasn't sure if it would work for me.  So I would be able to store standard pointers to any type in it (inside a map), then safely revert them when constructing my objects?  Wouldn't this throw errors at run-time, when I construct the first instance of an object type?  I guess I could write unit tests through each path that calls the factory method to see these errors near compile time.

Comment: All defined independently... but all defined identically... at compile time. I'm not at all sure I understand what you have in mind, but how about `typedef whatever type;` in a header shared by all of the classes?

Comment: @Beta I meant defined independently by being defined in the headers of each individual class, but identically, such that each of these definitions matched.  I think you `typedef` idea would probably be the best solution.  It wouldn't throw errors at compile time, but it would make it near impossible to make coding errors that lead to runtime errors.